# How to test login with Dusk on a Laravel/Lighthouse/Passport/Nuxt App?

Tags: laravel, laravel-passport, laravel-dusk, laravel-lighthouse

I've setup a Nuxt app with Laravel, and before doing too much I would like to setup Dusk testing. The app/login works great but I can't make it work on automated Dusk tests.

It use [lighthouse-graphql-passport-auth](https://github.com/joselfonseca/lighthouse-graphql-passport-auth) with the [setup described here](https://dev.to/joselfonseca/graphql-auth-with-passport-and-lighthouse-php-14g5). I think the issue is probably with the token generation in the Dusk environment.

Here is the example test which I can't make work:

```
public function testWithLoggedIn()
{
    $user = factory(User::class)->create([
        'email' => 'test@dusk.com',
        'password' => bcrypt('test'),
    ]);

    $this->browse(function ($browser) use ($user) {
        $browser->visit('/login')
                ->type('username', $user->email)
                ->type('password', 'test')
                ->press('Login')
                ->assertSee('Hello First User');
    });
}
```

So I already tried a few things. For example if I add this in the `setUp()` method:

```
$this->artisan('passport:install');
$client = Client::findOrFail(2);
config()->set('lighthouse-graphql-passport.client_id', 2);
config()->set('lighthouse-graphql-passport.client_secret', $client->secret);
```

I get this error:

```
Error: GraphQL error: Client authentication failed
```

I also tried to add the same informations as I have locally for the oauth_clients. Unfortunately the redirect is different ('http://local.test' for local, and 'http://apache' when testing in dusk).

```
DB::table('oauth_clients')->insert([
        'id' => 2,
        'name' => 'Apps Password Grant Client',
        'secret' => 'SWjOP5Y8NzxEx7z3dlaVs08VDUWgrSl96l4V9JO3',
        'redirect' => 'http://apache',
        'personal_access_client' => 0,
        'password_client' => 1,
        'revoked' => 0,
        'created_at' => '2020-02-17 11:02:33',
        'updated_at' => '2020-02-17 11:02:33',
    ]);
```

This returns this kind of error:

```
Error: GraphQL error: The provided authorization grant (e.g., authorization code, resource owner credentials) or refresh token is invalid, expired, revoked, does not match the redirection URI used in the authorization request, or was issued to another client.
```

How should I test this application? Everything will be behind this login screen so there is probably a way, and if needed I can change the login method (maybe without using passport).

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the second solution with the `DB::table` insertion worked.

The missing thing was to wait a little in the test before the assert (with an `->pause(300)` or a `->waitFor('.selector', 0.2)`.

For example this worked:

```
$this->browse(function ($browser) use ($user) {
        $browser->visit('/login')
                ->type('username', $user->email)
                ->type('password', 'test')
                ->press('Login')
                ->waitFor('.admin-dashboard', 0.2)
                ->assertSee('Welcome');
    });
```